# How to "install" Python code from CMake?

Tags: python, jenkins, cmake

I have a mainly c++ project that I use CMake to manage. After setting `cmake_install_prefix` and configuring, it generates makefiles which can then be used to build and install with the very standard:

```
make
make install
```

At this point, my binaries end up in `cmake_install_prefix`, and they can be executed with no additional work. Recently I've added some Python scripts to a few places in the source tree, and some of them depend on others. I can use CMake to copy the Python files+directory structure to the `cmake_install_prefix`, but if I go into that path and try to use one of the scripts, Python cannot find the other scripts used as `imports` because `PYTHONPATH` does not contain `cmake_install_prefix`. I know you can set an environment variable with CMake, but it doesn't persist across shells, so it's not really "setup" for the user for more than the current terminal session.

The solution seems to be to add a step to your software build instructions that says "set your PYTHONPATH". Is there any way to avoid this? Is this the standard practice for "installing" Python scripts as part of a bigger project? It seems to really complicate things like setting up continuous integration for the project, as something like Jenkins has to be manually configured to inject environment variables, whereas nothing special was required for it to build and execute executables built from c++ code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python provides `sys.path` list, which is used for search modules with `import` directives. You may adjust this list before include your modules:

**script1.py**:

```
# Do some things useful for other scripts
```

**script2.py.in**:

```
# Uses script1.py.
...
sys.path.insert(1, "@SCRIPT1_INSTALL_PATH@")
import script1
...
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
# Installation path for script1. Depends from CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.
set(SCRIPT1_INSTALL_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/<...>)

install(FILES script1.py DESTINATION ${SCRIPT1_INSTALL_PATH}

# Configure 'sys.path' in script2.py, so it may find script1.py.
configure_file("script2.py.in" "script2.py" @ONLY)

set(SCRIPT2_INSTALL_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/<...>)
install(FILES script2.py DESTINATION ${SCRIPT2_INSTALL_PATH}
...
```

If you want script2.py to work both in build tree and in install tree, you need to have *two instances* of it, one which works in build tree, and one which works after being installed. Both instances may be configured from single `.in` file.

---

In case of compiled executables and libraries, similar mechanism is uses for help binaries to find libraries in non-standard locations. It is known as RPATH.

Because CMake

- knows every binary created (it tracks `add_executable` and  `add_library` calls),
- knows linkage between binaries (`target_link_libraries` call is also tracked),
- has full control over linking procedure,

CMake is able to **automatically** adjust RPATH when install binaries.

In case of Python scripts CMake doesn't have such information, so adjusting linkage path should be performed *manually*.

Comment: So it seems this will produce a working "installed" version. Is there anyway to have, in addition, a more immediate/intermediate way to run the scripts for development. That is, change a .py file, run that whole CMake procedure, then try/test it seems a bit clunky. Is there anyway to make the scripts work "in-place" as well (from the source tree, for example)?

Comment: `Is there anyway to make the scripts work "in-place" as well (from the source tree, for example)?` In the scripts you may use some sort of annotations, like `sys.path.append(/path/to/scriptA) # $$scriptA$$`. When want to install a script, firstly find all `$$...$$` lines in it and replace them with appropriate expressions, then install resulted file. In any case **installed** script should be *different* from one **in source tree** (unless your want to adjust environment or script's parameters).

Comment: Use `install(PROGRAMS script1.py...)` if you want the script to be executable. [`PROGRAMS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/install.html#installing-files) does this.